# Shopify (Liquid): Syntax error expected close_square but found comma

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am creating an array in Shopify (Liquid) and I get an error,

```
            {% assign numbers = [   
                                    "One", 
                                    "TWo", 
                                    "three",
                                    "bla"                                   
                                 ] 
            %}
```

> Line 126 — Liquid syntax error: Expected close_square but found comma
>   in "{{[                                       "One","TWo", "three","bla" ] }}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to create an array like this in liquid.

Instead, you can use the `split` filter to create an array from a string.

```
{% assign numbers = "one,two,three,four" | split: "," %}
<pre>{{ numbers | inspect }}</pre>
```

You can also create an empty array and feed it with the `push` filter

```
{% comment %} +++ Creates an empty array +++ {% endcomment %}
{% assign numbers = "" | split: "" %}
<pre>{{ numbers | inspect }}</pre>
{% comment %} +++ Feed the beast +++ {% endcomment %}
{% assign numbers = numbers | push: "one" %}
<pre>{{ numbers | inspect }}</pre>
{% assign numbers = numbers | push: "two" %}
<pre>{{ numbers | inspect }}</pre>
```